# Upstairs plugs are not working

Tags: electrical

I woke up to none of the plugs upstairs working. So I went down stairs to the fuse box and the breaker for upstairs sockets had been tripped. As I flipped it back on, it made a loud bang and flashed.  What should I do?

Comment: You have a short in the circuit, and probably a fried mouse in the walls.  Unplug everything that is plugged in and check all the wires.  Will probably need an electrician to find the problem, unless you know how to check circuits.

Comment: I have checked for mice and rats and have no evidence that there are any as i havent found any droppings or holes in the house

Comment: @CurtBill does it smell like a cookout? If a small animal is fried in the wall, it would probably smell like bbq.

Comment: Fried mouse is just one cause, usually the easiest for sudden short in circuit.  A device failing bad or falling in water is another.  A hot wire becoming loose and touching ground is also one.  Look for burn marks on outlets to maybe narrow down the search.

Comment: just unplug stuff until it no longer instantly pops. try to go in batches so you don't have to keep re-energizing the heavy load. if everything is unplugged and unscrewed and it still pops, you need to call an electrician.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a dead short on that circuit.  Could be a device plugged in to a socket that has failed, could be an outlet or wiring that has failed.

Calling an electrician at this point is a perfectly good idea.  But there are some things that someone comfortable working around electricity might do.

What I would probably do is

- Leave the breaker off.
- Go to every outlet on the circuit and examine it for anything unusual (marks, soot, liquid spills, impact damage, burn smells, etc.) Something caused the circuit to fail and I would be looking for evidence about what that was.
- Unplug *all* devices/cords/etc. from *every* outlet on the circuit.
- If nothing suspicious found, I might try the breaker one more time now that the devices are unplugged.
- If the breaker tripped again, or if I found any damage or something suspicious with one of the outlets, time to call an electrician.
- If the breaker stayed on this time, I'd look more closely at what was plugged in. Probably one of the devices has damage and should be disposed of.

Comment: Given the story so far, the OP should go for the electrician.

Comment: Agreed. Breakers aren’t supposed to flash-bang when they trip. Electrician time.

Answer (score 2):

You should call an electrician, for goodness sake!